# Gtk.Widget.draw(): error, 1 parameters needed for signal draw; 0 given

Tags: python, gtk, signals

I want to update my Gtk.DrawingArea when an event triggers.

Check out the code, it doesn't work: **1 parameters needed for signal draw; 0 given**

```
event = threading.Event()
area = Gtk.DrawingArea

area.connect("draw", self.__DrawingArea_DrawSignal)

def __DrawingArea_DrawSignal(self, widget, context):
   pass

if event:
    area.emit('draw')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't and can't just emit signals from outside the object like that.

It's not totally clear what you are trying to do, but you can call `area.queue_draw()` if you want to ensure a redraw happens.